# Subtract and find the difference of a value or volume

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I have a volume measurements of brain parts (optic lobe, olfactory lobe, auditory cortex, etc), all the parts will add up to total brain volume. As shown in the example dataframe here.

```
a   b   c   d   e   total
1   2   3   4   5   15
2   3   4   5   6   20
4   6   7   8   9   34
7   8   10  10  15  50
```

I would like to find the find the difference of brain volume if I subtract one components out of total volume. 
So I was wondering how to go about it in R, without having to create a new column for every brain part.

```
For example: (total - a = 14, total - b =13, and so on for other components).

total-a total-b total-c total-d total-e
14      13      12      11      10
18      17      16      15      14
30      28      27      26      25
43      42      40      40      35
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
dat[, "total"] - dat[1:5]
#   a  b  c  d  e
#1 14 13 12 11 10
#2 18 17 16 15 14
#3 30 28 27 26 25
#4 43 42 40 40 35
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want also the column names, then one `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 gather(var, val, -total) %>%
 mutate(var = paste0("total-", var),
        val = total - val) %>%
 spread(var, val)

  total total-a total-b total-c total-d total-e
1    15      14      13      12      11      10
2    20      18      17      16      15      14
3    34      30      28      27      26      25
4    50      43      42      40      40      35
```

If you do not care about the column names, then with just `dplyr` you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(-matches("(total)")), list(~ total - .))

   a  b  c  d  e total
1 14 13 12 11 10    15
2 18 17 16 15 14    20
3 30 28 27 26 25    34
4 43 42 40 40 35    50
```

Or without column names with just `base R`:

```
df[, grepl("total", names(df))] - df[, !grepl("total", names(df))] 

   a  b  c  d  e
1 14 13 12 11 10
2 18 17 16 15 14
3 30 28 27 26 25
4 43 42 40 40 35
```